Memory block with different input and output data width
I need to design a memory block where 64 things each 8 bit size are written in one at a time, while on the output, it is possible read 8 things simultaneously words at a time. This means that the output width is 64 bits rather than 8 bits. I believe this is possible but I am not sure how this can be designed.
The design goes onto an FPGA. What is the correct way to design such a memory module and is there a name for this like assymetric memory block or something like that?

"words of 8 bit size" are called bytes. words have 16 bits generally. I think you mean "input width is 64 bytes, output is 8 bytes"? Please edit your question for consistency and correct terminology. Also - how much memory (in byes) do you want in total? Hint : start by thinking about the address bus widths needed at input and output as well (once you define size).

@danmcb "Word" has no specific bit width, it is a generic term for a weighted group of a unspecified number of bits. The x86 world formed this limit to 16 bits, while not being the only one using it.

you are correct. so talking about "words" without saying what architecture is imprecise. It would be better to stick to "bytes", or be more specific.

by the way, that is why I used the word "generally".

Most FPGAs have dual port memory and it can be configured for the two ports to have different widths.  This would be the easiest way to do this in an FPGA because the read and write logic can be independent.  How you configure this is tool dependent, usually they have wizards for configuring on chip memories.
With single port memory, or if the memory can't be reshapes to your liking you would use a 64 bit wide memory, but then use byte enable lines to select the one byte you want to access.  A 64 bit memory would have 8 byte enable lines.  The bottom 3 bits of the byte relative address would be decoded to generate the byte enable while the remaining bits would select the 64 bit word.

I would prefer to write VHDL so the design can be used on Altera, Xilinx and also Microsemi devices.

It's possible to write memories on VHDL or verilog and have the tools under the correct memory macro.  However, tools differ on what they can infer, and it's also easy to accidentally write something that doesn't map to available block ram (typically missing input/output registerd).  It's best to put complex rams in a stand alone module.  That way you can start with a simple RTL memory then replace it with platform specific instances if needed.

If I understand you correctly, you want an 8-bit write port, and a 64-bit read port.
In which case you'll want a 64-bit wide 8-word RAM with byte enables.
On the read side, you can just read each 64-bit word directly. You would have a 3-bit address signal.
On the write side, you will want to create a byte-enable signal. You would start with a 6-bit address (byte address). The upper 3-bit feeds directly into the RAM address for the write port. The lower 3-bit of the address is used to create the byte enables using a simple bit shift (byteen = 1 << address[2:0]).
For the write data you just duplicate the 8-bit data 8 times to form the 64-bit word. The byte enable controls which is written.

If your RAM blocks dont support byte enables, you can use eight 8-bit RAMs. The read port is just all read data signals concatenated to form 64bit, with all RAMs getting the same read address. All of the write ports get the same address (upper 3bit), and the same data word, with the 8-bit byte enable signal used to determine which of the 8 RAMs will write.
